# golang call ruby dll

Tags: ruby, go, dll

I want to use golang to call ruby's dll,there is a function of c code：

```
long rb_num2int(VALUE);
```

and I use syscall in golang to call the function like that:

```
type VALUE uint64

func rb_num2int(val VALUE) int32 {
    ret, _, _ := Rb_num2int.Call(
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&val)),
    )
    return int32(ret)
}
```

finally when I use ruby to call the golang's so file, there have error :

```
Exception 0xc0000005 0x0 0x746e 0x6498cdd4
PC=0x6498cdd4
signal arrived during external code execution

syscall.Syscall(0x648af790, 0x1, 0xc0420600a8, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        C:/Go/src/runtime/syscall_windows.go:171 +0xf9
syscall.(*Proc).Call(0xc04205a4a0, 0xc0420600b0, 0x1, 0x1, 0x10, 0x67823060, 0x1, 0xc0420600b0)
        C:/Go/src/syscall/dll_windows.go:146 +0xa4
syscall.(*LazyProc).Call(0xc042074270, 0xc0420600b0, 0x1, 0x1, 0xc04203de98, 0x67784ae3, 0xc042052058, 0x0)
        C:/Go/src/syscall/dll_windows.go:302 +0x66
main.rb_num2int(0x2cbdc78, 0x0)
        C:/Users/ABC/go/src/sketchup/main.go:57 +0x8e
main.add(0x2cbdc78, 0x3, 0x5)
        C:/Users/ABC/go/src/sketchup/main.go:81 +0x36
rax     0x746e
rbx     0xc0420600a8
rcx     0xc0420600a8
rdi     0xc0420600a8
rsi     0x99
rbp     0x62f170
rsp     0x62f140
r8      0x62f1c0
r9      0xc21
r10     0x0
r11     0x8101010101010100
r12     0x62f1c0
r13     0x0
r14     0x0
r15     0x100
rip     0x6498cdd4
rflags  0x10202
cs      0x33
fs      0x53
gs      0x2b
```

Any suggestions on what should I do?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to write ruby's extension width golang,after ruby require it, I can call golang's function in ruby,Do you have good advice to solve this problem？

Comment: I think, that in your described case, there is no need to call a ruby function. If I understand correctly, you only want to convert an int64 to an int32. This can be handled in go as well, without any indirections.

Comment: maybe I didn't say clearly.My main program is sketchup,it provides an interface for ruby,rather than golang,but ruby can be writen extension width C/C++, of course ,golang can do it as well,because golang can be compiled into a .so file, ruby can require the .so file, after that I can call golang's function in ruby, I think that error is because of "uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&val))",could you help me?

Comment: You want to write a ruby extension in go, that can be called from ruby. That extension wants to access a ruby function from go. That ruby function is written in c. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, you  are right,so you think what should I do to modify the error?

Comment: I honestly do not know that. My 2 cents are: If you just want to convert an int64 to int32 it can be done easily in go without the need to call any c or ruby code. That would prevent the error, too. ;)

Comment: ok, thanks very much

Comment: Have a look at these resources [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879993/writing-a-ruby-extension-in-go-golang). That might help you to get a basic example to work.

Comment: thanks, but It doesn't fit me, I also want to call ruby in golang,maybe cgo suits me better